# Angular-material's tabs and ui-bootstrap's datepicker conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-material

I have a modal window with angular-material tabs and a ui-bootstrap datepicker. When I open datepicker, the text field moves up, and I cannot access either the datepicker or the field.

[**Here's a demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/m3y9cfm7)

Here's my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMaterial'])
.controller('myController', function ($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.showModal = function () {
    var modalInstance;
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: "addNew.html",
      controller: 'myController2',
      size: 'lg'
    });
  };
  $scope.showModal();
})
.controller('myController2', function ($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.datepickers = {
    start: false
  }

  $scope.openDatepicker = function ($event, which) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.datepickers[which] = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.dateFormat = 'mediumDate';
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="addNew.html">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Add</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
              <md-tab label="date">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="row form-group">
                        <label for="dateStart" class="col-sm-2 col-md-4 control-label">
                          Date&nbsp;Start
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                          <div class="input-group ui-datepicker">
                            <input type="text"
                                   class="form-control"
                                   name="dateStart"
                                   id="dateStart"
                                   datepicker-popup="{{dateFormat}}"
                                   ng-model="campaign.dateStart"
                                   is-open="datepickers.start"
                                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                                   ng-required="true"
                                   ng-click="openDatepicker($event, 'start')"
                                   close-text="Close"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon" ng-click="openDatepicker($event, 'start')">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
              <md-tab label="other tabs"></md-tab>
            </md-tabs>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used a css trick to [add the scroll bar in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/m3y9cfm7/1/), but it's not very neat. So I was wondering if there is a way to expand the tab height when the datepicker is opened or the datepicker is shown over a modal window like the select window opens.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want the modal to expand or the picker to float?

Comment: Add   overflow: auto; to this class md-tab-content.md-no-scroll{} and try.

Comment: @DTing I want the tab to expand, that will result in expanding the modal.  Modal is not a problem.

Comment: @stanze overflow: auto doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to have the dropdown datepicker appear as part of the regular document flow, that way it will occupy space and the tab picker will automatically make room for it.  It doesn't do that currently because it uses `.dropdown-menu`, to which Bootstrap adds [`position: absolute;`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/dropdowns.less#L32)

Just override like this:

```
.dropdown-menu[datepicker-popup-wrap] {
    position: static;
}
```

There are some other stylistic things you can do, but that is the basic principle.

[**Demo in jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/m3y9cfm7/2/)

Comment: i have tried this, but this has the `input-group-addon` height issue and it also makes width of input field wider also it move content below downward [link](http://jsfiddle.net/salalaslam/m3y9cfm7/3/), is there any other way??

Comment: I've got a similar problem with a modal, but instead for the tab to expand I want the modal to float over the whole page (like a modal normally does). Since you supplied this very good answer, would you also know how to float a bootstrap modal over the page when a button is clicked from within the tab? All tips are welcome!

Comment: @kramer65, have you tried [Angular UI's Bootstrap Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) implementation?  Other than that, the comment section isn't really enough room to diagnose much.  If you can summarize your problem with some code that you have and why it's not working, then you can [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and link to it here and I (and others) can take a look.